# How come I can see the outline of objects through other objects when I turn on freestyle?

Tags: rendering, mesh, freestyle

I turned on freestyle and can see the outline of meshes behind my main mesh. Why is this? I think I figured it out, the object was a plane. Is there anyway to get around this without redoing the object? 
[image]

Comment: What settings are you using? Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project. [Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand your scene and settings.

Comment: What do you mean setting?

Comment: Freestyle has many controls... how are you using it?